# Mark as tick or cross on Progress Dialog in android after successful completion

Tags: android

I want to show tick or cross on progress dialog after successful `sign in` or `wrong credentials` in android. As expected thing showing in the picture. Is there any method in android? Currently I am using `ProgressDialog`

[image]

Comment: crete custom layout for this, and use alertdialog with progress bar

Answer (score 3):

you can create your own custom view xml and pass it to your dialog

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);     
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog_layout);
```

You can add any view in that xml and change their visibility.

Reference for creating custom layout dialog 
http://www.pcsalt.com/android/create-alertdialog-with-custom-layout-using-xml-layout/

And for "Tick"(Success) animation you can use some custom view like the following
https://github.com/chengli3209/SuccessLoadingView